# Editing GtkWidget attributes/properties

Tags: python, styles, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

In most pygtk widget pages, they contain sections called 'Attributes', 'Properties', and 'Style Properties'. How can I change these properties and attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to change properties:

1. As in zheoffec's answer, use the `set_property()` function (or `set_style_property()` for style properties.) This function is actually not necessary in Python, but it is there for completeness because it is part of the C API.
2. Use the `props` attribute. Any property that you find in the documentation can be accessed through this attribute. For example, `btn1.props.label = 'StackOverflow'` and `btn1.props.use_underline = False`.
3. Use the getter and setter functions as frb suggests. These are also only present because they are part of the C API, but some people prefer them over the `props` attribute. Also, there is no guarantee that any particular property will have getter and setter functions! Usually in a well-designed C API they will be there, but it is not required.

For style properties, I believe the only option is #1. For "attributes", well, these are simply Python attributes. To access the `allocation` attribute, use `btn1.allocation`.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the widget there widget.pros list:

```
button = gtk.Button()
for pspec in button3.props:
  print pspec
  #print button3.get_property(pspec.name)
```

Output:

```
<GParamObject 'related-action'>
<GParamBoolean 'use-action-appearance'>
<GParamPointer 'user-data'>
<GParamString 'name'>
<GParamObject 'parent'>
<GParamInt 'width-request'>
<GParamInt 'height-request'>
<GParamBoolean 'visible'>
<GParamBoolean 'sensitive'>
<GParamBoolean 'app-paintable'>
<GParamBoolean 'can-focus'>
<GParamBoolean 'has-focus'>
<GParamBoolean 'is-focus'>
<GParamBoolean 'can-default'>
<GParamBoolean 'has-default'>
<GParamBoolean 'receives-default'>
<GParamBoolean 'composite-child'>
<GParamObject 'style'>
<GParamFlags 'events'>
<GParamEnum 'extension-events'>
<GParamBoolean 'no-show-all'>
<GParamBoolean 'has-tooltip'>
<GParamString 'tooltip-markup'>
<GParamString 'tooltip-text'>
<GParamObject 'window'>
<GParamBoolean 'double-buffered'>
<GParamUInt 'border-width'>
<GParamEnum 'resize-mode'>
<GParamObject 'child'>
<GParamString 'label'>
<GParamObject 'image'>
<GParamEnum 'relief'>
<GParamBoolean 'use-underline'>
<GParamBoolean 'use-stock'>
<GParamBoolean 'focus-on-click'>
<GParamFloat 'xalign'>
<GParamFloat 'yalign'>
<GParamEnum 'image-position'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In PyGTK, `GtkWidget` is the base class that all other widget classes (including ones you might make yourself) inherit from.

As far as setting properties goes, you probably noticed you can't set them directly:

```
btn1.label = "StackOverflow"
```

In PyGTK, you need to prefix the names of the properties with `set_`, like this:

```
btn1.set_label("StackOverflow")
```

If there's a `-` in the property name, like with `use-underline`, turn them into underscores, like `set_use_underline`. I'd like to say that I don't think this use of getters and setters is very pythonic.

Here's a full working program, taken from the [ZetCode tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/firststeps/) and modified.

```
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Buttons")
        self.set_size_request(250, 200)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        btn1 = gtk.Button("Button")
        btn1.set_label("StackOverflow")
        btn1.set_use_underline(False)

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()

        fixed.put(btn1, 20, 30)

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

        self.add(fixed)
        self.show_all()


PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but take for example pygobject's Gtk.RadioToolButton, which doesn't have a seperate `join_group()` method, except a method that creates a new `RadioToolButton` and adding it to a group. If I want to modify an existing `RadioToolButton`s group, I will need to modify a property (which I've just found out how to do ;) (see my answer)).

Answer (score 1):

You can change a Widget property by using the `Gtk.Widget.set_property(property, value)` method. `property` should be a string.

Comment: it is actually a GObject method, which will work on objects that are not widgets as gtk.TextTag for example.