# Set style property in PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I have a very simple PyGObject application:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_border_width(5)

        self.progress = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.progress.set_fraction(0.5)

        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.box.pack_start(self.progress, True, True, 0)

        self.add(self.box)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()


win = Window()
Gtk.main()
```

[image: Application]

I want to have the progress bar thicker. So I found that there is a style property for that:

```
Name                        Type    Default  Flags  Short Description
min-horizontal-bar-height   int     6        r/w    Minimum horizontal height of the progress bar
```

However, I seem not to be able to set the style property in any way I tried.

1) I tried to use CSS:

```
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

css = b"""
GtkProgressBar {
    border-color: #000;
    min-horizontal-bar-height: 10;
}
"""

style_provider.load_from_data(css)

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
    style_provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
)
```

But I got an error:

`GLib.Error: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: <data>:4:37'min-horizontal-bar-height' is not a valid property name (3)`

2) I tried `set_style_property` method and all methods described in [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184441/674475).

a)

`self.progress.set_property('min-horizontal-bar-height', 10)`

`TypeError: object of type 'GtkProgressBar' does not have property 'min-horizontal-bar-height'`

b)

`self.progress.set_style_property('min-horizontal-bar-height', 10)`

`AttributeError: 'ProgressBar' object has no attribute 'set_style_property'`

c)

`self.progress.min_horizontal_bar_height = 10`

`GLib.Error: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: <data>:4:37'min-horizontal-bar-height' is not a valid property name (3)`

d)

`self.progress.props.min_horizontal_bar_height = 10`

`AttributeError: 'gi._gobject.GProps' object has no attribute 'min_horizontal_bar_height'`

e)

`self.progress.set_min_horizontal_bar_height(10)`

`AttributeError: 'ProgressBar' object has no attribute 'set_min_horizontal_bar_height'`

Any idea how to get thicker progress bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS, you must prefix the name of the style property with a dash and the name of the class to which the style property belongs:

```
GtkProgressBar {
    -GtkProgressBar-min-horizontal-bar-height: 10px;
}
```

They are not meant to be set in code, so there is no corresponding setter method to `style_get_property()`.

Comment: Awesome! Is there a good documentation for this and generally how to use CSS for styling in GTK? Like for example for separate widgets in runtime, styling whole app etc.? I had a really hard time finding anything relevant.

Comment: [Here's the documentation for styling with GTK CSS](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#GtkCssProvider.description). It could be better but it's a pretty decent overview of what you can do.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Where exactly is this "prefix with class name and dash" *really* documented? Not in the linked page, anyway.

Comment: That's a weirdly aggressive way to put it. Did you think I'm trying to point people to the wrong page on purpose? No, they've reorganized the CSS documentation in the latest release. [Here's the page I originally linked to.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.18/GtkCssProvider.html#GtkCssProvider.description) It's at the bottom of that "Description" section.