# How to get the attachment values when a widget has been attached to a grid

Tags: python, gtk3, gobject

This will show all attributes and their values of an existing widget: (I got the idea from user285594 at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180320/editing-gtkwidget-attributes-properties/65564870#65564870))

```
obj = [widget identifier]
    for pspec in obj.props:
        print(pspec.name)
        name = pspec.name.replace('-', '_')
        props = eval("button.props." + name)
        print(props)
```

Unfortunately, I can't find the attachment values when the widget has been attached to a grid. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368)

Answer (score 1):

The attachment and packing values are [child properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html#GtkGrid.child-properties), not properties, so you have to retrieve them with [`child_get_property()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Container.html#Gtk.Container.child_get_property).